# "There was an error processing the thumbnail for stream..." - paperclip + imageMagick in Rails 3 and Windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, imagemagick, paperclip

I've recently installed paperclip and image magick in Rails 3. Both seem to be installed properly (running identity version confirms that image magick has been installed)

When trying to upload images, I'm always confronted with an error about processing the thumbnail. The few solutions I did see mentioned adding the output format ("after adding the desired output format to the style: `:medium => ["300x300>", :png]` the error vanishes.") but I don't know what the means.

I feel like **this line** (in environment.rb) might cause an issue

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "C:/Program Files (x86)/ImageMagick-6.7.4-Q16/"
```

My model looks like this:

```
...
has_attached_file :upload, :styles => { :medium => "200x200#", :thumb => "100x100#" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
...
```

And the form for submission looks like this:

```
<%= form_for :post, @post, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
...
<%= f.submit 'Submit'%>
<%= f.file_field :upload %>
<% end %>
```

While my migration looks like:

```
  class AddUploadToPost < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def self.up

      add_column :posts, :upload_file_name, :string
      add_column :posts, :upload_content_type, :string
      add_column :posts, :upload_file_size, :integer
      add_column :posts, :upload_updated_at, :datetime
    end

    def self.down

      remove_column :posts, :upload_file_name
      remove_column :posts, :upload_content_type
      remove_column :posts, :upload_file_size
      remove_column :posts, :upload_updated_at

    end
  end
```

Comment: mmm... not sure paperclip is windows-friendly... it relies heavily on [Cocaine](https://github.com/thoughtbot/cocaine), a tool to build command-line calls. You should try it (never thought i'd recommend someone to try cocaine, duh) to see if it works with windows shell. Anyway, if you really want to do some serious web development, you will spare yourself a LOT of pain by switching to a *nix (linux and such) environnement, in a virtual machine for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've moved to a virtual linux box, which has since solved the problem